# configure custom.css for Jupyter Notebook in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

How do you use custom.css in vscode when running Jupyter Notebook.  I definately do NOT want to use themes as I've got everything working fine outside vscode using a custom.css.

Comment: Hey crs. I'm a developer on this extension. I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you are looking to do here. Themes are the extensible way to customize colors in Visual Studio code. Are you looking for support for an extension like this which can hack in custom css?
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What I'm trying to do is to use a custom.css file to change the appearance of the notebook.  It works fine outside vscode, but not inside vscode.  The custom.css file goes in the custom directory of the Jupyter config directory.  I'm a computer trainer and I wanted to use the notebook alonside lots of C and C++ examles, but without customisation the notebook looks terrible.  Yes I could use themes, but I like my own customisation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this css customization is not supported in VS Code or the notebook interface in particular. VS Code provides theming options to support color customization and does not support editing the css directly. There are some extension that attempt to provide custom css support but this are all unofficial and unsupported.

Comment: Cheers Ian,  That's a shame.  Just have to run outside vscode.

Answer (score -1):

despite missing official support ([issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12862)), we can use https://github.com/drcika/apc-extension#apciframestyle to do that.

Install the apc-extension and enable it. After the required vscode restart, add css in "apc.iframe.style" setting (as described in the documentation), and it just works as expected.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34729758)

Comment: Just added some simple description of how to use the vscode extension. p.s. "may" answer the question - it's confirmed to be working.